# how java read URL from csv file?

Tags: java, android, url, dataset, uri

I am trying to read a dataset file with a CSV extension, it just has two columns: 1- URL and 2- Lable (malicious or benign) and 2 rows, its a test sample from a bigger dataset, so how can I do that?

csv file content:

| https://www.google.com | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| http://atualizacaodedados.online | 1 |

first, I import URI

```
import java.net.URI;
```

and then I try this code:

```
 Scanner dataset = new Scanner(new FileReader("urltest.csv"));
         dataset.useDelimiter(",");
         URI uri[]= new URI[2];
         while(dataset.hasNext()) {
             for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                 uri[i] = new URI(dataset.next());
                 System.out.println(uri[i]);
            }
         }
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: https://www.google.com
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2966)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3147)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3162)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
    at feturesExtraction2.datasetFile.main(datasetFile.java:22)
```

Comment: Use your debugger to see what `dataset.next()` is returning. Based on the error, `URI` is unhappy about something with it, such as perhaps it starting with a space. Note that [there are a few CSV libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/23?sort=created) that will be more reliable for more flavors of CSV than will your use of `Scanner`.

Comment: Nothing simpler than reading a csv file. Start with reading line for line. After that you only have to split the line in two. As you did not post an example of your file we cannot go into details. The last thing you need is a library as you can better do all yourself. Nor do you need Scanner.

Comment: @blackapps example of my file: https://www.google.com 0
http://atualizacaodedados.online 1
as i said its just have 2 column URL and lable

Comment: @blackapps ok, I did that.

Comment: This feels like a leading space before “http”. Try and .trim() dataset.next()

Comment: @blackapps check the post again, there is a picture at the end.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I try that, same error.

Comment: A csv file should only contain text. So you should post two text lines. Unclear what you posted now. If it contains anything else then plain text you are not supposed to call it a csv file. You also posted it in such a way that there is no separator. What did you use as separator? A comma? Or what?

Comment: **a.** you don't show what the delimiter in your file *actually* is. As someone has said, csv files are *text* so please post text formatted as code, not a picture of the csv and **b.** your code won't work, whatever the delimiter is, as you are trying to create two URIs out of each line, which only contains *one*

Answer (score 0):

You should trim it like this

```
dataset.next().trim()
```

maybe you need to cast string before using this